# On the direction of the induction current

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

Some time ago, I started looking back at my notes from high school and now I have a question regarding the direction of the induction current I've been thinking about for days. It might be too easy for you experts, but here it goes anyway.

First, notice please that - whenever I refer to the direction of the *induction current* - I mean the direction the electrons move in (i.e. from minus towards the plus-pole). The problem goes as follows (as I found out yesterday, it is basically the same problem discussed [here](https://www.khanacademy.org/science/physics/magnetic-forces-and-magnetic-fields/magnetic-flux-faradays-law/v/emf-induced-in-rod-traveling-through-magnetic-field) at the end of the video) and is released to [Lenz's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenz%27s_law):

> A conductor of length $L$ is moved to the right (as shown in the picture) with constant velocity $v$ perpendicular to the field lines of a homogeneous magnetic field. During the movement an induction current $I_i$ can be registered. Determine the direction of the induction current.

[image]

At first I thought that the electrons of the induction current would move from the front to the back, and I proved this by contradiction as follows:

For the sake of contradiction, assume that the electrons flow from the back to the front. What would be the consequences? With the left-hand rule, one may confirm that the current flow would induce a magnetic field around the conductor, which would increase $B$ in the closed circuit. However, this is a contradiction to the law of conservation of energy, because the change in the $B$ would again generate a voltage that would cause an increase in $B$, etc. The contradiction therefore shows that the electrons will flow in reverse (i.e.: from the front to the back), which is the same conclusion of the video.

At the same time, however, the [Lorentz force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorentz_force) states that the movement of the conductor causes the charges in the conductor to split. The direction can be determined with the three-fingers-rule: the electrons will collect at the back, so this end will become the negative pole. But this is exactly the opposite of what was found out by the contradiction before.

Which approach is wrong and why?

Thanks in advance

---

Edit: Sorry for the confusion. I hope this image makes the problem statement clear

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The voltage induced in the conductor is in the direction that would produce a current opposing any change in he magnetic flux through a loop. The loop in pink ahead of the rod is reducing in area, and so a current in that loop would tend to increase the magnetic field to oppose the change in flux. The yellow loop behind the rod is increasing in area, and the same voltage in the rod would generate a current in the opposite direction around the loop, decreasing the field behind the rod in order to oppose the change in flux.

Comment: I interpreted the picture differently: there is a U-shaped yellow wiere and an orange cross piece completing the loop. The pink stuff is just where the orange cross-piece is going. IOW, there is no "pink loop".

Comment: Exactly @Peter! And this would support the first claim, right? But then, why is the approach with Lenz's law false?

Comment: @NickD, the loops do not need to be physical. The voltage builds up the same whether there is a physical loop or not.

Comment: The induction current that is induced by the voltage is flowing through a conductor, not through a vacuum.

Comment: @user265131, the back of the rod is negative, so electrons would (if possible) flow clockwise in the pink loop producing an upward field in front of the rod, and anticlockwise in the yellow loop producing a downwardfield magnetic field there. This is the same as your second statement. Note that the electrons tend to flow from the back of the rod to the front through the rest of the loop, not through the rod.

Comment: @NickD, nothing is said about conductors except for the rod. But the electrons accumulate anywat.

Comment: @user265131, electrons move through the rod to the back, and this makes the back negative. Unless there is a conductor the flow then stops. However the direction is the same as if the electrons could go all the way around.